# Extract date from string using Regex.named_capture

Tags: regex, elixir

I would like to take a string like "My String 2022-01-07" extract the date part into a named capture.

I've tried the following regex, but it only works when there's an exact match:

```
# Does not work
iex> Regex.named_captures(~r/(?<date>\$?(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2})?)/, "My String 2021-01-01")
%{"date" => ""}

# Works
iex> Regex.named_captures(~r/(?<date>\$?(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2})?)/, "2021-01-01")
%{"date" => "2021-01-01"}
```

I've also tried this without luck:

```
iex> Regex.named_captures(~r/([a-zA-Z0-9 ]+?)(?<date>\$?(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2})?)/, "My String 2021-01-01")
%{"date" => ""}
```

Is there a way to use named captures to extract the date part of a string when you don't care about the characters surrounding the date?

I think I'm looking for a regex that will work like this:

```
iex> Regex.named_captures(REGEX???, "My String 2021-01-01 Other Parts")
%{"date" => "2021-01-01"}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want

```
Regex.named_captures(~r/(?<date>\$?\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2})/, "My String 2021-01-01")
```

Your regex - `(?<date>\$?(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2})?)` - represents a named capturing group with `date` as a name and a `\$?(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2})?` as a pattern. The `\$?(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2})?` pattern matches

- `\$?` - an **optional** `$` char
- `(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2})?` - an **optional** sequence of four digits, `-`, two digits, `-`, two digits.

Since the pattern is not anchored (does not have to match the whole string) and both consecutive pattern parts are optional and thus *can match an empty string*, the `~r/(?<date>\$?(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2})?)/` regex **matches the first empty location (empty string) at the start of the `"My String 2021-01-01"` string.

**Rule of thumb**: If you do not want to match an empty string, make sure your pattern contains *obligatory* patterns, that must match at least one char.

Comment: Thanks a ton! I just realized the optional $ char shouldn't have even been in there in the first place and was a copy/paste from another regex I was working on.

Answer (score -1):

Extract Date only:

```
void main() {

String inputString = "Your String 1/19/2023 9:29:11 AM";
  RegExp dateRegex = new RegExp(r"(\d{1,2}\/\d{1,2}\/\d{4})");
  Iterable<RegExpMatch> matches = dateRegex.allMatches(inputString);
  for (RegExpMatch m in matches) {
    print(m.group(0));
  }
}
```

This will output:
1/19/2023

Extract Date and time:

```
void main() {

String inputString = "Your String 1/19/2023 9:29:11 AM";
  RegExp dateTimeRegex = new RegExp(r"(\d{1,2}\/\d{1,2}\/\d{4} \d{1,2}:\d{2}:\d{2} [AP]M)");
  Iterable<RegExpMatch> matches = dateTimeRegex.allMatches(inputString);
  for (RegExpMatch m in matches) {
    print(m.group(0));
  }
}
```

This will output: 1/19/2023 9:29:11 AM

Comment: Unrelated to Elixir.